# How to escape commands in a bashrc alias?

Tags: linux, bashrc

I need to occasionally touch a file with the current timestamp as the filename.
I would do so this way:

```
touch `date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M"`.txt
```

However, I'd like to define an alias for this. When I try adding to the bashrc this:

```
alias td="touch `date \"+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M\"`.txt"
```

the result is that the filename is the same during the entire session, since the `date ..` gets calculated just once during login...

How can I get the command to expand only when I call the alias? Or must I use a function for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shell expands the command line containing the `alias` command and passes something like `td=touch 2010-09-17_21-54.txt` to the `alias` command. You need to protect the special characters in the alias definition from expansion. The easiest way is to use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
alias td='touch `date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M"`.txt'
```

Then `td` is an alias for `` touch `date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M"`.txt `` as desired.

Although it's not an issue here, I recommend using `$(…)` instead of `` `…` ``, so as to avoid difficulties with complex commands (backquotes have arcane and nonportable quoting rules, whereas dollar-parenthesis works intuitively):

```
alias td='touch $(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M").txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is perfect almost always. For those times when you MUST use double-quotes instead of single-quotes, the following works:

```
alias td="touch \`date \"+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M\"\`.txt"
```